# How to send raw email using "node-ses" without providing access key and secret key ? or by using IAM role

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

While sending mail using node-ses we need to provide access key and secret key at the time of client creation. 
I want to get rid of these keys and would like to handle this using IAM role access for lambda function in which this code is running.

```
 ses = require('node-ses'), 
 client = ses.createClient({ key: config.get('awsSettings.accessKey'), secret: config.get('awsSettings.secretKey') }),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: If you don't specify access and secret keys, the Lambda function will assume them from the role that is assigned to the Lambda function. Ensure that `ses:SendEmail` or `ses:SendRawEmail` permissions are allowed

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get around using some form of [SES credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html), when using *either* SES API or SES SMTP service interfaces. In the case of `node-ses`, this library implements [SendEmail and SendRawEmail SES API](https://github.com/aheckmann/node-ses) calls, and therefore is subject to the credential requirements of this service.

In both cases, these credentials are either issued by SES when you enable the service, and/or are configured via an IAM user, the secret and access keys associated with that user.  These credentials are used for authentication by both SES SMTP and API services, and function as user name and password for this purpose.

You **cannot** use an IAM role to substitute for the use of SES credentials; SES requires email clients to use these one of these credentials for SES service authentication.

To summarize from [Using Credentials With Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html):

> - If you want to access the Amazon SES API, then use AWS access keys (Access key ID and secret access key), which consist of the Access key ID and secret access key for the designated IAM user account.
> - If you want to access the Amazon SES SMTP interface, you use SES SMTP credentials, which consist of a user name and password. Although
>     your Amazon SES SMTP credentials are different than your AWS access
>     keys and IAM user access keys, Amazon SES SMTP credentials are
>     actually a type of IAM credentials.

Comment: I don't see SMTP referenced in the question.  Does `node-ses` use SMTP instead of the SES API?

Comment: Good point. I had SMTP on the brain today. I have updated the answer to reflect the proper use of SES credentials on both API and SMTP services.

Comment: @RodrigoM thanks for the reply.
I have managed to send email without passing secret key and access key while creating ses client.
var client = ses.createClient();
and it worked inside aws lambda. This might have worked b'coz I gave all the permissions to lambda.